# CISCO enterprise router recommendation

Tags: router

I need a cisco enterprise router recommendation. I am currently using a Cisco 2821 Gigabit Router single WAN router. Ultimately, the new Router will become my primary router while the old Cisco 2821 will become a backup router.

**Main Criteria**

1. I am serving a **web service** and an **E-mail server** as well. **100-200 users** could be use my web service.
2. I want the router to be a **Gigabit Router**. Right now **my fiber connection bandwidth is 100 Mbps**.
3. **I may upgrade the connection to 200 Mbps. The router should work with 100 Mbps ISL connection**.
4. The router should support **Dual WAN connections** and **Load Balancing**.
5. Is an enterprise router meaning it should have **Firewall**, **Instruction 
      Prevention**, and **SSL VPN**.
6. It should be capable of **simultaneously handling multi-user connections**.